# Are forces of gases intensive or extensive?

Tags: forces, pressure, ideal-gas

What am I wrong at in here:

I read that pressure is an intensive property.
According to this and to $P=\frac{nRT}{V}$, can this be true:
$(1)$: When $V$ is constant, increasing $n$ won't increase $P$, but rather will decrease $T$.
 $(2)$: When $T$ is constant, increasing $n$ won't increase $P$, but rather will increase $V$.

Noting that $P=\frac{F}{A}$:
For $(1)$, when $V$ is constant then $A$ is constant, and because $P$ is intensive that doesn't depend on $n$ increase, then $F$ is also constant, and does not change by changing $n$.
For $(2)$, when $V$ increses then $A$ increases, and because $P$ is intensive that doesn't depend on $n$ increase, then $F$ increases to compensate for the increase in $n$.

Comment: Force is not a property, but it does change with area if pressure is constant.

Comment: Related: "How is pressure an intensive property?" (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449201)

Answer (score 1):

> (1): When $V$ is constant, increasing $n$ won't increase $P$, but rather will decrease $T$.
>
> (2): When $T$ is constant, increasing $n$ won't increase $P$, but rather will increase $V$.

Or you can keep both $V$ and $T$ constant, in which case increasing $n$ does increase $P$.

Saying that pressure is "intensive" doesn't mean that pressure can't change. It means that the pressure in one half of room is the same as the pressure in the whole room (if the room is in equilibrium). In contrast, the volume in one half of the room is only half of the volume of the whole room, so volume is extensive rather than intensive.

Comment: Is $(1)$ true? decreasing the temperature won't effect the pressure?

Comment: @Muhammad It depends on what you hold constant. If you decrease $T$ but hold $V$ and $n$ constant, then $P$ will decrease. If you decrease $T$ but hold $P$ and $n$ constant, then $V$ must decrease. And so on. All of these are consistent with $PV=nRT$, and all of them are consistent with $P$ being an intensive property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused as to what an [intensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) is.

As an example, suppose that we have a room filled with some gas with $(P, V, T, n).$

Now let us say that we consider only half of the room. The new state will be $(P, \dfrac{V}{2}, T, \dfrac{n}{2})$.

The quantities which did not change(P & T) are called intensive properties.

The quantities which did change(V & n) are called extensive properties.

All the statements you measured are dependent on the type of process and system.

1. When $V$ is constant and you increase $n$.

   - If your system is an insulated box, then $P$ and $T$ will both change.
   - If your system is a conducting box, then $T$ will not change but $P$ will.
2. When $T$ is constant and you increase n.

   - If you have a conducting sealed box, then $P$ will change and $V$ will not change.
   - If you have a conducting piston-cylinder, then $P$ will not change and $P$ will change.